Why does Coq solve_in_Union tactic fail directly but works through assertion of identical goal?
I have a puzzling situation in Coq where I'm working with relations and ensembles. I have defined coercions between them and a tactic to solve membership goals:
Require Import Lia Reals Lra Classical_sets List Ensembles Relations_1.
Import ListNotations.

Notation "x ∈ A" := (In _ A x) (at level 40).
Notation "A ⋃ B" := (Union _ A B) (at level 30).
Notation "⦃⦄" := (Empty_set _).
Notation ℝ := R.

Fixpoint list_to_ensemble {U : Type} (l : list U) : Ensemble U :=
  match l with
  | [] => ⦃⦄
  | x :: xs => Union U (Singleton U x) (list_to_ensemble xs)
  end.

Notation "⦃ x ⦄" := (Singleton _ x).
Notation "⦃ x , y , .. , z ⦄" :=
  (@list_to_ensemble _ (cons x (cons y .. (cons z nil) ..)))
  (format "⦃ x , y , .. , z ⦄").

Lemma In_Union_def : forall (U : Type) (A B : Ensemble U) (x : U),
  x ∈ (A ⋃ B) <-> x ∈ A \/ x ∈ B.
Proof.
  intros; split; [apply Union_inv | intros [H1 | H1]; [apply Union_introl; auto | apply Union_intror; auto]].
Qed.

Coercion rel_to_ens {A} (R : Relation A) : Ensemble (A * A) := 
  fun p => R (fst p) (snd p).

Coercion ens_to_rel {A} (E : Ensemble (A * A)) : Relation A := 
  fun x y => E (x,y).

Lemma x_y_In_implies_rel : forall A (R : Relation A) x y, (x, y) ∈ R <-> R x y.
Proof.
  intros; split; auto.
Qed.

Ltac solve_in_Union :=
  simpl; auto;
  match goal with
  | [ |- ?x ∈ Singleton _ _ ] => 
      apply Singleton_intro; (try reflexivity; try nia; try nra)
  | [ |- ?x ∈ Union _ ?A ?B ] => 
      apply In_Union_def; solve [ left; solve_in_Union | right; solve_in_Union ]
  | [ |- ?G ] => fail "Goal not solvable"
  end.

When proving a simple membership property:
Section Example.
  Open Scope R_scope.
  Let R : Relation ℝ := ⦃ (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,5),(2,6),(3,5),(4,5),(4,6) ⦄.

  Lemma lemma_example : R 1 1.
  Proof.
    apply x_y_In_implies_rel. unfold R. try solve_in_Union.
    assert ((1, 1) ∈ ⦃ (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,5),(2,6),(3,5),(4,5),(4,6) ⦄) as H1 by solve_in_Union.
    auto.
  Qed.
End Example.

When I try to solve the goal with try solve_in_Union, my goal is exactly:
(1, 1) ∈ ⦃(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,5),(2,6),(3,5),(4,5),(4,6)⦄

Strangely, using solve_in_Union directly on this goal fails. However, if I assert exactly the same goal text and try to prove it with solve_in_Union, it works:
Even more puzzling, if I pattern match the goal and print it:
match goal with
| [ |- ?G ] => idtac G
end.

It shows exactly the same text that works in the assertion.
Why does solve_in_Union fail on the original goal but succeed on an assertion of the identical goal? What's the fundamental difference between these two seemingly identical situations?
As for the Coq version I am using, when I type coqc -v into the terminal I get
coqc -v
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.19.2
compiled with OCaml 5.2.0

Could you provide enough information to compile your code? What did you Require, and what if anything did you define that you are using? Probably less relevant, but while you're at it you might also mention your Coq version.

Have you tried  Set Printing All. in case there is some "invisible ink" that is not shown?

Doing Set Printing All. and take a sharp look at the goal we see
that in the first (non-working) case, the goal is
In (prod RbaseSymbolsImpl.R RbaseSymbolsImpl.R)
  (@rel_to_ens RbaseSymbolsImpl.R
  (@ens_to_rel RbaseSymbolsImpl.R
  (@list_to_ensemble (prod RbaseSymbolsImpl.R RbaseSymbolsImpl.R)
  (@cons (prod RbaseSymbolsImpl.R RbaseSymbolsImpl.R)
  (@pair RbaseSymbolsImpl.R RbaseSymbolsImpl.R
  (IZR (Zpos xH)) (IZR (Zpos xH)))

  ....

and in the second (working) case the goal is
In (prod RbaseSymbolsImpl.R RbaseSymbolsImpl.R)
  (@list_to_ensemble (prod RbaseSymbolsImpl.R RbaseSymbolsImpl.R)
  (@cons (prod RbaseSymbolsImpl.R RbaseSymbolsImpl.R)
  (@pair RbaseSymbolsImpl.R RbaseSymbolsImpl.R (IZR (Zpos xH))
  (IZR (Zpos xH)))

so it seems like somehow the coercions ens_to_rel and rel_to_ens get in the way of the unfolding that is needed for the matching to work.
Actually all that is quite a mouthful, and when we have spotted the problem it is better to just do Set Printing Coercions.
So the R is a Relation with a coercion, but the term in your assert is an Ensemble.
Definition your_R : Relation R := ⦃ (1,1), (1,2) ⦄.
Definition your_assert  := ⦃ (1,1), (1,2) ⦄.
Set Printing All.
Print X.
Print Y.

prints
X = ens_to_rel ⦃(1, 1),(1, 2)⦄
 : Relation ℝ

Y = ⦃(1, 1),(1, 2)⦄
 : Ensemble (ℝ * ℝ)

There is no rule that matches the former which is why the Ltac solve_in_Union fails.
In particular, your goal is like
(1, 1) ∈ rel_to_ens (ens_to_rel ⦃(1, 1),(1, 2)⦄)

which cannot be simplified because the two coercions are not definitionally inverses.  They are partially applied functions
and cannot be further reduced.

In this case the function actually has an argument (which is an argument to In).
If you define Definition foo T e (x y : T) : (x,y) ∈ rel_to_ens (ens_to_rel e)  = (x,y) ∈ e := eq_refl.  and rewrite with that just before you do the solve_in_Union it will solve the example you gave. but it feels like a hack...
